# php variable echo's with proper value inserts into db wrong

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a variable in a php form with a variable `$mrn`. When I submit the data via the `$_POST[];` method a php script is called to pull up another page and echo what was entered in the form and submit it to a db table. When I check the db table the value that gets entered into the form and successfully echoed is not what gets inserted into the db. All the other data in the form posts correctly and successfully. This same variable does not post correctly to the db on any of the forms.  I am taking a look at this post [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983579/html-form-changing-echoed-variables-but-not-database?rq=1) as it is relevant. I am unfamiliar with the functions and am reading it over.

Here is my insert_records php

```
    <?php
    $page_title = 'Insert Outcomes Data';
    include('php_includes/header.html');

    // Connect to the database
    include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");

    // Gather the posted data into local variables
    $mrn = $_POST['mrn'];
    $add_hosp_dispo = $_POST['add_hosp_dispo'];
    $date_alt_lvl_cr_sts = $_POST['date_alt_lvl_cr_sts'];
    $actual_discharge_time = $_POST['actual_discharge_time'];
    $actual_discharge_date = $_POST['actual_discharge_date'];
    $gcs_outcome = $_POST['gcs_outcome'];

    // Get user IP Address
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

    // Form data error handling
    if($mrn == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing data.";   
    } else {
        // End form data error handling
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nys_outcome_info (
            mrn, 
            final_hosp_dispo,
            date_alt_lvl_care,
            actual_discharge_time,
            actual_discharge_date,
            gcs,
            ip_address, 
            record_insert_dtime
        )
        VALUES(
            '$mrn', '$add_hosp_dispo', '$date_alt_lvl_cr_sts', '$actual_discharge_time', 
            '$actual_discharge_date', $gcs_outcome,
            '$ip', now()
        )";
    }

    if (mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql)) { 
      echo "<h3>Demographics have been inserted successfully, you will be auto-directed to the  form.<br /><br /></h3>";
      echo "MRN: $mrn <br />";
      echo "Date of Alternate Level of Care Status: $date_alt_lvl_cr_sts <br />";
      echo "Actual Discharge Time: $actual_discharge_time <br />";
      echo "Actual Discharge Date: $actual_discharge_date <br />";
      echo "GCS Outcome: $gcs_outcome <br />";
      echo "From IP Address: $ip <br />";
      echo "On " .date("Y-m-d") ." at " .date("h:i:sa");
      header("refresh:3; url=outcomes.php");
    } else {
      printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db_connect));
    }

    include('php_includes/footer.html');
    ?>


Form page code

    <?php
     $page_title = 'Outcomes';
     include('php_includes/header.html');
     ?>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="outcomes_data">
        <form class="form" action="insert_outcomes_data.php" method="post" name="outcomes_data" id="outcomes_data">
            <h3>Outcomes</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Medical Record Number / Visit ID (Number 17 Characters):</div>
                <input class="form-control" id="mrn" name="mrn" type="text" maxlength="17">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Additional NY Hospital Discharge Dispositions</div>
                <select class="form-control" id="add_hosp_dispo" name="add_hosp_dispo">
                    <option value="50">50 - Discharged to Shelter/Homeless</option>
                    <option value="51">51 - Discharged to Foster Care</option>
                    <option value="52">52 - Died-Full Code</option>
                    <option value="53">53 - Died-Withdrawal of Care</option>
                    <option value="54">54 - Died-DNR/DNI</option>
                    <option value="55">55 - Died-Brain Death</option>
                    <option value="56">56 - Transferred to TBI Rehabilitation Facility or Dedicated TBI Unit</option>
                    <option value="57">57 - Discharged or Transferred to Spinal Cord Injury Rehabilitation Facility or Dedicated Spinal Cord Injury Unit</option>
                    <option value="58">58 - Transfer out of State</option>
                </select>

                <a href="#add_hosp_dispo_info" data-toggle="collapse">More Info</a>

                <div id="add_hosp_dispo_info" class="collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li>The disposition of the patient when discharged from the final hospital.</li>
                        <li>Full code: Patient was NOT a DNR/DNI (Do Not Resuscitate/Do Not Intubate) at the time of death, care was not withdrawn.</li>
                        <li>DNR/DNI: Patient had a Do Not Resuscitate/Do Not Intubate order, resuscitation was not provided at the time of death.</li>
                        <li>Care Withdrawn: Treatment was withdrawn or stopped prior to the patient's death. Documentation of "terminal weaning" or "discontinuation of life support" may suggest that care was withdrawn.</li>
                        <li>Brain Death Criteria: Select only if brain death criteria was met and the patient was declared dead using this criteria.</li>
                        <li>This field is crucial for modeling.</li>
                        <li><strong>Data Source:</strong> Discharge Summary, Nurses Notes, Case Manager/Social Service's Notes</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Date of Alternate Level of Care Status</div>
                <input class="form-control" id="date_alt_lvl_cr_sts" name="date_alt_lvl_cr_sts" type="date">

                <a href="#date_alt_lvl_cr_sts_info" data-toggle="collapse">More Info</a>

                <div id="date_alt_lvl_cr_sts_info" class="collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li>An order for discharge was written for the patient but because of social issues (i.e. homeless status, no bed available at an adult home or long term care facility) the patient remains at the facility only for shelter.</li>
                        <li>Collected as YYYY-MM-DD</li>
                        <li><strong>Data Source:</strong> Physician Order sheet, Social Work Notes, Nurses Notes</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Actual Discharge Time</div>
                <input class="form-control" id="actual_discharge_time" name="actual_discharge_time" type="time">

                <a href="#actual_discharge_time_info" data-toggle="collapse">More Info</a>

                <div id="actual_discharge_time_info" class="collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Collected as HH:MM military time.</li>
                        <li>This field is used to calculate the length of stay (time from admission to hospital discharge).</li>
                        <li><strong>Data Source:</strong> Nursing Notes</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Actual Discharge Date</div>
                <input class="form-control" id="actual_discharge_date" name="actual_discharge_date" type="date">

                <a href="#actual_discharge_date_info" data-toggle="collapse">More Info</a>

                <div id="actual_discharge_date_info" class="collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Collected as YYYY-MM-DD.</li>
                        <li><strong>Data Source:</strong> Nursing Notes</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Glasgow Coma Score</div>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="gcs_outcome" name="gcs_outcome" min="3" max="15">

                <a href="#gcs_outcome_info" data-toggle="collapse">More Info</a>

                <div id="gcs_outcome_info" class="collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li>GCS range is from 3-15.</li>
                        <li><strong>Data Source:</strong> Discharge Summary, Nurses Notes</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p></p>

            <button type="submit" id="btn_outcomes_data">Insert Outcomes Data</button>
            <span id="status"></span>

        </form>
    </div>

<?php
include('php_includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: On a side note, you echo `The form submission is missing data.` but you always try to run a query, since the code is outside of the `else`

Comment: `$outcomes_mrn` is used for nothing..

Comment: Have you tried doing a printf of the query that inserts?  To me, that all looks good, so I'm wondering what the form's code is.

Comment: I'll post the form's code now.

Comment: What is the defined type for `MRN` in the table? Also, what would be an example value for it?

Comment: @FirstOne the type is INT(17) an example value can be 123456789

Comment: MRN is uppercase?! check that on db also; since mysql is case sensitive

Comment: @L.Kelmendi that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SQL Keywords are case-insensitive (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc), but are often written in all caps. On some setups table and column names are case-sensitive. In your case MRN should be mrn. That's why u are getting no data inserted.